# $k[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-x^3)\cong k[x]$, where $k$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory

This is generalizing from a previous question, which asks to prove that $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)\cong k[x]$. The way I proved that was by using the homomorphism $\phi:k[x,y]/(y-x^2)\to k[x]$, $\phi(\overline{f(x,y)})=f(x,x^2)$, which is well defined, since $$f(x,y)\in (y-x^2)\implies y-x^2\mid f(x,y) \implies 0\mid f(x,x^2) \implies f(x,x^2)=0$$ is trivially a surjective homomorphism, and is injective, since $$f(x,x^2) = 0\implies x^2 \mathrm{\,is\,a\,root\,of\,} f(x,y)\mathrm{\,in\,} k[x][y] \implies y-x^2\mid f(x,y)\mathrm{\,in\,} k[x][y]=k[x,y]$$ However, when I try to generalize this to $k[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-x^3)$, by defining $\phi:k[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-x^3)\to k[x]$, $\phi(\overline{f(x,y,z)})=f(x,x^2,x^3)$, I can show everything except injectivity. What I get is that $$f(x,x^2,x^3)=0\implies x^3 \mathrm{\,is\,a\,root\,of\,} f(x,x^2,z)\mathrm{\,in\,} k[x][z] \implies z-x^3\mid f(x, x^2,z)\mathrm{\,in\,} k[x][z]$$ or that $$f(x,x^2,x^3)=0\implies x^2 \mathrm{\,is\,a\,root\,of\,} f(x,y,x^3)\mathrm{\,in\,} k[x][y] \implies y-x^2\mid f(x, x^2,z)\mathrm{\,in\,} k[x][z]$$
Assuming the result, that $f=g+h$, where $y-x^2\mid g$ and $z-x^3\mid h$, the problem with my previous approach is that it is impossible to isolate either $g$ or $h$ without destroying some of the structure necessary to prove divisibility. How might it be possible to fix this?

Comment: Are you also interested in a simpler approach to show isomorphisms of this sort? or are you primary interested in fixing your own approach?

Comment: I think there's a typo in your last display. Anyway, in the older problem how did you know that $f(x,x^2) = 0$ implied this divisibility statement? I think this technique needs to be upgraded somewhat.

Comment: I used the euclidean algorithm over the field of fractions of $k[x]$.

Comment: Okay, that allows you to write $f(x,y) = (y-x^2)g$. But now $g$ is an element of $g(x)[y]$. What then?

Comment: I know already (and have been asked to prove) that if $R$ is a UFD then so is $R[X]$, and therefore, since $f$ has a prime factorization, one of those irreducible elements must have root $x^2$, since we are working over a domain. Then you apply Gauss's lemma – a polynomial is irreducible over the ring iff it is irreducible over the field of fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there are polynomials $f$ with $\phi(\overline f)=0$ and $f\notin (y-x^2,z-x^3)$.
Among these. let $f_0$ have minimal degree in $z$. If $f_0$ has positive degree $k$ in $z$, say $f(x,y,z)=p_0(x,y)+p_1(x,y)z+\ldots +p_k(x,y)z^k$, then $f_0(x,y,z)-p(x,y)z^{k-1}x^3$ is equivalent to $f_0$ but of lower degree in $z$. We conclude that $f_0$ has degree $0$ in $z$, i.e., is only a polynomial in $x$ and $y$. Again, among all polynomials with $\phi(\overline f)$ and $f\notin(y-x^2,z-x^3)$ and degree zero in $z$ let $f_1$ be of moinimal degree in $y$. By a similar argument, we conclude that $f_1$ is a polynomial in $x$ alone. As it is mapped to the zero polynomial, we conclude that $f_1=0$, i.e., our polynomilas were in $(y-x^2,z-x^3)$ to begin with.

This simple method works more generally when we consider $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n]/(x_2-f_2(x_1), x_3-f_3(x_1,x_2),\ldots,x_n-f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_{n.1}))$.

Comment: That generalizes very nicely to an induction argument. Thanks.